# Why do I get scheduler Invalid Date error on JasperServer 6.0.1?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am migrating the jasperserver from 3.7 to jasperserver 6.0.1, now in new jasperserver i want the date format to be dd/mm/yyyy but by default the date format is yyyy-mm-dd.
For this i changed the jasperserver_config.properties file at

> apache-tomcat-7.0.65\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\bundles\jasperserver_config.properties

i changed it to

```
    # Used for parsing and formatting dates by server
    date.format=dd/MM/yyyy
    datetime.format=dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
    time.format=HH:mm:ss

    # Used for parsing and formatting dates by calendar component (UI).
    # Pattern for date should match appropriated pattern from server properties.
    # The format for calendar component can be combinations of the following:
    # d  - day of month (no leading zero)
    # dd - day of month (two digit)
    # o  - day of year (no leading zeros)
    # oo - day of year (three digit)
    # D  - day name short
    # DD - day name long
    # m  - month of year (no leading zero)
    # mm - month of year (two digit)
    # M  - month name short
    # MM - month name long
    # y  - year (two digit)
    # yy - year (four digit)
    calendar.date.format=dd/mm/yyyy
    calendar.datetime.format=dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss
    calendar.time.format=HH:mm:ss
```

It changed the date format but when I am going to schedule any report the date field is showing as invalid date(see below). Can some one help me in changing the date format that work correctly all over jasperserver

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug with this up to version 6.10 of JasperReports Server, see [bug report](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-server/issues/3637). I've had to use the solution #2 at the time being.

**Solution #1**

If possible, update to version 6.10.

**Solution #2**

This solution is a bit lengthy but works properly if both steps (changing the source, generating the optimized js file) are done:

You have to edit a js file for this to work properly. Use the pattern you need for your case.

> in file `/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.5.0a/apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/scripts/scheduler/model/job.js` you have to change this:
>
> row 5
>
> from:
>
> ```
>   var UI_DATE_PATTERN = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm";
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
>   var UI_DATE_PATTERN = "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm";
> ```
>
> row 766
>
> from:
>
> ```
> data.trigger.startDate = moment(data.trigger.startDate).format(SERVICE_DATE_PATTERN);
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
>  data.trigger.startDate = moment(data.trigger.startDate,UI_DATE_PATTERN).format(SERVICE_DATE_PATTERN);
> ```

[Source](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-server/issues/3637)

*Optimized Java Script*

*NOTE:* Because of the optimized Javascript files (which is not the one which is edited as far as I remember), keep in mind you might need to recreate the optimized js file - since the optimized one is the one which is used by JRS. This was the case in v 5.6.x at least:

> 1. Create a working directory where you can copy JavaScript files and install and run the required scripts. In
>      this example, the directory is called Working.
> 2. Create a subdirectory for a copy of the JavaScript files from JasperReports Server. This directory is called `jssources`.
> 3. Copy the following directories from the JasperReports Server directory, `<js-webapp>`, to `js-sources`:
>
>    • Copy `<js-webapp>/scripts` to `js-sources/scripts`.
>
>    • Copy `<js-webapp>/fusion` to `js-sources/fusion` (optional, Pro version only)
> 4. Back up your `js-sources` directory.
> 5. Create a `js-optimization-output` directory for the output of the optimization process.
> 6. Download and install `node.js` from http://nodejs.org/. Place the `nodejs` folder directly in your Working folder.
> 7. Download `r.js`, a requirejs optimization file, from http://requirejs.org and place it directly in the Working folder.
> 8. Make your changes to the JavaScript files in `Working/js-sources`.
> 9. Open a command line tool and run the commands to optimize the JavaScript. The following example is for Windows, it places the output in the Working/js-optimization-output folder:
>
>    `% cd Working`
>
>    `% nodejs\node r.js -o js-sources\scripts\build.js appDir=js-sources\scripts baseUrl=. optimize=uglify2 dir=js-optimization-output`
> 10. Copy the optimized scripts from `js-optimization-output` to `<webapp>/optimized-scripts` (where webapp is the location of your JRS)
> 11. Reload the web app in the app server to see the changes.

[Source](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/842095/jasperserver-56-how-regenerate-optimized-js-files)

*NOTE:* Keep in mind to clear your browser cache if there are problems after doing all this.

Comment: I have tried all the steps suggested by you but it do generated any optimised scripts, i believe this could be due to the fact that there is no fusion directory in 6.0.1.

Comment: This directory is optional as far as I understand it, since only professional versions might have it. I suppose there went something wrong when following those steps.

Comment: Sorry i downloaded incorrect require js i have corrected that it is now generating the optimised scripts, it looks promising, i will update you if it works, thanks @tobi6 :)